# Probability of failure of a system made of n identical SPOF components

Tags: probability

A fuel pump is correctly functionning $a \%$ of the time.
So it has probability of failure of $(1 - \frac{a}{100})$ (I'm not already sure that I can say that).
The system is made of $n$ independant fuel pumps. If any of the pumps fails, the whole system fails.

What's the probability of the whole system to fail ?

Getting all the pumps to function at the same time would be $(\frac{a}{100})^{n}$. So is the probability for the whole system to fail $(1 - (\frac{a}{100})^{n})$ ?

Then, considering 2 systems for high-availability: if a pump fails in systemA with probability $(1 - (\frac{a}{100})^{n})$, what is the probability of systemB to also fail, that is to say, for the 2 systems to fail at the same time ?

Is it simply $(1 - (\frac{a}{100})^{2n})$ ?

Or is it something linked with the birthday paradox ? Assuming that a pump AFR is $\frac{1}{365}$ and that when it fails, it fails the whole system for a whole day, given than 1 pump has failed in systemA, the probability of any other pump in systemB to also fail would be $(1 - \frac{365!}{(365 - (n + 1))!} \cdot \frac{1}{365^{n+1}})$, wouldn't it ?

($n + 1$ is the one failed pump form system A and the $n$ pumps for systemB).

Comment: can you show us how you arrived at that answer??

Comment: I have no idea, I'm looking for an answer and understand that I have a lot to learn (just bought Statistics in a Nutshell)

Comment: Assuming independence, the probability that both system A fails and System B fails is $\left(1 -\left(\frac{a}{100}\right)^{n}\right)^2$